# How can I reset my BIOS using Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, bios

I need to reset the BIOS. I took a look into my laptop, but the CMOS battery and the jumper are covered with a lot of stuff and I don't feel like taking all of that out. So is there a way of resetting the BIOS using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

```
modprobe nvram
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvram
```

Then reboot.

This resets the CMOS memory on most systems.

Comment: Most PC systems (so almost all desktop and server computers) don't have `/dev/nvram`. I've only really seen that on embedded systems. -1

Comment: This is the correct answer, at least on Ubuntu 16+. You just need to modprobe nvram.  I locked myself out of IPMI remote console by disabling a buggy USB chipset in BIOS earlier and this resolved it.

Comment: /dev/nvram skips anyway the first 14 bytes of the real CMOS memory which contains the RTC (real time clock). To write also those 14 bytes you need a small C program, but usually is not needed.

Comment: Does this reset bios administrator password ? I am struggling with it now :/